# Display glitches in games and occasionally videos

Tags: windows-10, gaming, debug

I've been experiencing display glitches intermittently in various games and once or twice in YouTube videos. They take quite a number of different forms and I'll post a number of links below to short, demonstrative GIFs. I'm not sure how to isolate the problem to hardware or software (let alone to a particular hardware component).

Some points that come to mind about my system/setup:

- Windows 10 64-bit
- GPU is a Sapphire Radeon R9 Fury currently on driver 17.4.3, although the problem has persisted across a number of driver updates. It's connected to my monitor over DisplayPort
- I've been going back and forth with Sapphire support and as a result have updated my motherboard BIOS, cleared my CMOS, reset to factory default driver settings, and reseated the GPU in a different PCIe slot apparently to no avail

Some links to GIFs as promised:

- [Diablo 3, #1](https://giphy.com/gifs/C7KrQSQXiGfOU/html5)
- [Diablo 3, #2](https://giphy.com/gifs/747hN32Fb7euI/html5)
- [Rocket League #1](https://giphy.com/gifs/IJw2DM8iLt9kY/html5)
- [Rocket League #2](https://giphy.com/gifs/11NeWJcbup8C8E/html5)
- [Rocket League #3](https://giphy.com/gifs/163VNOtatHehO/html5)
- [Shadow of Mordor #1](https://giphy.com/gifs/ZZl0fFdGvzj1u/html5)
- [Shadow of Mordor #2](https://giphy.com/gifs/D61XgakPzpKlG/html5)
- [Shadow of Mordor #3](https://giphy.com/gifs/2xcw0XbcZ2Zr2/html5)

The YouTube glitches are harder to capture but have involved flickering, horizontal black bars across the video in question, when they occur.

I would appreciate advice on what to test to isolate the problem and even tips on how I might reproduce the glitches reliably!

I was pointed to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1022416) as  a possible duplicate of this one. I think I may well be suffering the same problem and some of the same symptoms, but the only answer there (disable hardware acceleration in my browser) does little to help me, as my main issues are not browser-related. Additionally, my question is not a request for a *solution* per se, but rather for help identifying the root of the problem.

#### Next day update:

Tracked down [MemtestCL on GitHub](https://github.com/ihaque/memtestCL) and ran it a few times on the Fury's VRAM. I ran 100 iterations at a time and a summary of 4 such runs is presented below.

```
400 iterations over 256 MiB of memory on device Fiji

Moving inversions (ones and zeros):     0 failed iterations (0 total incorrect bits)
Memtest86 walking 8-bit:                4 failed iterations (4 total incorrect bits)
True walking zeros (8-bit):             2 failed iterations (2 total incorrect bits)
True walking ones (8-bit):              3 failed iterations (3 total incorrect bits)
Moving inversions (random):             1 failed iterations (1 total incorrect bits)
True walking zeros (32-bit):            4 failed iterations (4 total incorrect bits)
True walking ones (32-bit):             2 failed iterations (2 total incorrect bits)
Random blocks:                          1 failed iterations (261982 total incorrect bits)
Memtest86 Modulo-20:                    11 failed iterations (11 total incorrect bits)
Integer logic:                          0 failed iterations (0 total incorrect bits)
Integer logic (4 loops):                0 failed iterations (0 total incorrect bits)
Integer logic (local memory):           0 failed iterations (0 total incorrect bits)
Integer logic (4 loops, local memory):  0 failed iterations (0 total incorrect bits)
```

Comment: The root of the problem looks like it's small defects in the video RAM of your Sapphire Radeon R9 Fury GPU. You can test this by temporarily swapping in another graphics card if you can.

Comment: The multiple failed iterations in the "Next day update" to your question look worrisome and worthy of further investigation, especially because the pattern of the visual artifacts in some of your linked .gif files and the pattern of the visual artifacts in the linked question is similar.

Comment: Yeah - looks like I'll be RMAing the card. Thanks for the guidance @karel!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the problem looks like it's small defects in the video RAM of your Sapphire Radeon R9 Fury GPU. You can test this by temporarily swapping in another graphics card if you can.

The multiple failed iterations in the "Next day update" to your question look worrisome and worthy of further investigation, especially because the pattern of the visual artifacts in some of your linked .gif files and the pattern of the visual artifacts in the [linked question](https://superuser.com/questions/1022416/firefox-43-puts-black-spots-on-display) is similar.

Comment: The RMA is still underway but I was able to test the GPU in another computer, with the same behaviours. I'm pretty sure this is right but I'll update if I hear further from the manufacturer.