# Can't boot computer after Windows 10 glitched red screen

Tags: windows-10, crash

I was playing Minecraft and listening to music a few hours ago on my computer, when I suddenly got some weird red screen with glitched pixels almost everywhere.

I first thought the game was the problem, so I tried to close it, but my computer restarted, and is now stuck before Windows itself boots on.

I tried to access the BIOS by pressing F10, F12, and the Del keys, but none of them worked.

I think I said everything I know so far.
If you know how to help me, or need some more information, please tell me.

Regards.

Comment: It might be a hardware issue... anything from a dead video card to bad HDD. You need to do tests and provide information for anyone to even guess.

Comment: Could be a driver issue for the video card. Unplug the powercord (and if its a laptop, remove battery), then press the power button a few times and then hold it for another 30 seconds to drain any residual electic from the system. Then plugin the powercord and insert battery if removed, now see if you can get into bios. If so, but the system does not start, go into safe mode.

Comment: Sounds like video hardware fault or failure. Windows does not have any red screen errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display glitches in games and occasionally videos](https://superuser.com/questions/1204443/display-glitches-in-games-and-occasionally-videos)

Comment: So, I tried to unplug and replug my Video-Card and both RAM bars I had, and the same problem occured : Stuck on a screen with blue pixels.

Comment: I also tried to boot it without the Video-Card, but the speaker answered with a long beep followed by two shorter ones, any ideas from now on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a few hours of searching, I managed to reset the BIOS, and succesfully noticed that the problem was coming from the Video-Card

Only thing I can think to do now is to get a new one